# US succession to the president list: What is it and how long does it go?

Tags: united-states, president, succession

In the US, I often hear that there is a list of people that can take power if everyone in front of them is dead or incapable of doing the job or resigns.

Like if the President is ever out, then the VP gets in charge. If the VP is out, then the speaker of the house gets it.

I'm pretty sure that list goes a lot further than that, even if the US never needed more than the VP before an election.

So how far does the succession list goes, and what is the order? Also, as a bonus: Am I wrong that only the VP was ever needed? Was there ever a situation where they had to go further down the list?

Comment: Is there anything here not answered by: [United States presidential line of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_line_of_succession)?

Comment: Or [this question here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30527/could-the-speaker-of-the-house-become-president-if-they-weren-t-born-in-the-usa/30528#30528)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could the Speaker of the House become president if they weren’t born in the USA?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/30527/could-the-speaker-of-the-house-become-president-if-they-weren-t-born-in-the-usa)

Comment: @divibisan that post contains the answer, but it also contains a lot of other information, so I don’t think that it’s a duplicate.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Containing extra information isn't an issue.

Comment: This question may be considered a [borderline duplicate](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4589/26455). The list contained in the dup target was not required to answer that question, but is required to answer this question. This question also asks: *Was there ever a situation where they had to go further down the list?*, a question not answered in the dup target. IMHO this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @RickSmith yeah its an unfortunate duplicate. The information was already answered on the site yes, but it is within the answer of a question that is asking something pretty different than what is currently asked.

Comment: Note if the VP becomes President, the new President can then appoint a new VP (subject to senate confirmation) and that New VP would then be top of the line of succession.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is, officially, eighteen positions long, [illustrated here](https://www.voanews.com/us-presidential-line-succession) (with a typo).

It goes:

1. Vice President
2. Speaker of the House of Representatives
3. President *Pro Tempore* of the Senate
4. Secretary of State
5. Secretary of the Treasury
6. Secretary of Defense
7. Attorney General
8. Secretary of the Interior
9. Secretary of Agriculture
10. Secretary of Commerce
11. Secretary of Labor
12. Secretary of Health and Human Services
13. Secretary of Housing and Urban Development
14. Secretary of Transportation
15. Secretary of Energy
16. Secretary of Education
17. Secretary of Veterans Affairs
18. Secretary of Homeland Security

You are correct that we've never gone past the VP, which we've only gotten to nine times.

It's important to note that the depth of the presidential 'bench,' if you will, varies because the requirements to become President are stricter than those necessary to become, e.g. Speaker of the House.  [As such, there may be people in the statutory line of succession that would be skipped.](https://www.factcheck.org/2008/05/presidential-eligibility-and-the-line-of-succession/)

You can't even inherit the duties of the job if you couldn't hold the job itself. So this holds even though [no one below the VP actually becomes the President, they simply assume the duties and responsibilities thereof](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/3/19).

Per 3 U.S. Code § 19(a)(1) *emphasis added*:

> If, by reason of death, resignation, removal from office, inability, or failure to qualify, there is neither a President nor Vice President to discharge the powers and duties of the office of President, then the Speaker of the House of Representatives shall, upon his resignation as Speaker and as Representative in Congress, **act as President.**

Legally the term 'act as President' is decidedly and explicitly not the same as 'becomes the President.' And later on in that same part of the USC it's explained that if at any point the President or Vice President become competent to discharge the duties of their office, the successor is dismissed - this is NOT true, however, if someone higher up the chain - but *not* the President or VP - becomes competent. Irrelevant in cases of death, but in the case of sickness or kidnapping, it would be possible for someone down the chain to need to assume the duties until the crisis was resolved.